# Python Pandas: How to drop rows by time?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to keep rows with time that are between 6am (morning) and 12am (midnight), how should I do it?

This is my dataframe:
[image]

and this is the datatype:
[image]

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
daytime_start = '06:00:00'
daytime_end = '23:59:59'
mask = (df['Time'] >= daytime_start) & (df['Time'] <= daytime_end)
filtered_df = df.loc[mask]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`df.between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html):

```
df.set_index('Date Time').between_time('6:00', '23:59').reset_index()
```

Comment: After applying that, the table looks like is in index mode (some of the headers displayed higher except the index header), how do I put it back into the dataframe format?

Comment: @hongkongbboy to reset the index of a dataframe, use the `reset_index` method

Answer (score 1):

using query

```
df.query('index < @start_remove or index > @end_remove')
```

using loc

```
df.loc[(df.index < start_remove) | (df.index > end_remove)]
```

using date slicing

This includes the end points

```
pd.concat([df[:start_remove], df[end_remove:]])
```

Comment: Link go bad over time. You should summarize the relevant information of the link in your answer

Comment: @Paul H Thank you, I'll remember that.

Comment: You can use the *edit* button to fix this answer now